# How to Solve java.lang.StackOverflowError from following Code?

Tags: android

How to Solve java.lang.StackOverflowError from following Code?

My Code is:-

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
      private static final String ACTION_ADW_PICK_ICON="org.adw.launcher.icons.ACTION_PICK_ICON";
      private boolean mPickerMode=false;
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      GridView g=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
      g.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
      g.setColumnWidth(iconSize);
      g.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_SPACING_UNIFORM);
      g.setVerticalSpacing(iconSize/3);
      g.setOnItemClickListener(this);
      IconsAdapter adapter=new IconsAdapter(this,iconSize);
      g.setAdapter(adapter);
      if(getIntent().getAction().equals(ACTION_ADW_PICK_ICON)){
        mPickerMode=true;
      }
  }
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
    if(mPickerMode){
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        try{
            bitmap=(Bitmap) adapter.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if(bitmap!=null){
            intent.putExtra("icon",bitmap);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        }else{
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        }
        finish();
    }
  }
  private class IconsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private int mIconSize;
    public IconsAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mIconSize = iconsize;
        loadIcons();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        //return mThumbIds[position];
        return ((BitmapDrawable)mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mThumbs.get(position))).getBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void loadIcons() {
        mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        final Resources resources = getResources();
        final String packageName = getApplication().getPackageName();

        addIcons(resources, packageName, R.array.icon_pack);
    }
    private void addIcons(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
        final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
        for (String extra : extras) {
            int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
            if (res != 0) {
                final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                if (thumbRes != 0) {
                    mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SatckTrace is:-

```
08-24 17:10:50.105: INFO/dalvikvm(633): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/graphics/drawable/DrawableContainer$DrawableContainerState;.getChildCount:I
08-24 17:10:50.105: INFO/dalvikvm(633):   method requires 8+20+0=28 bytes, fp is 0x418fa30c (12 left)
08-24 17:10:50.115: INFO/dalvikvm(633):   expanding stack end (0x418fa300 to 0x418fa000)
08-24 17:10:50.115: INFO/dalvikvm(633): Shrank stack (to 0x418fa300, curFrame is 0x418fa4b0)
08-24 17:10:50.155: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(633): Shutting down VM
08-24 17:10:50.155: WARN/dalvikvm(633): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-24 17:10:50.405: DEBUG/dalvikvm(633): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 46% free 3170K/5831K, external 1903K/2179K, paused 7ms+6ms
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633): java.lang.StackOverflowError
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.indexOfStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:274)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.access$000(StateListDrawable.java:253)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:95)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:306)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:70)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:749)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
08-24 17:10:50.485: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(633):     at android.content.res.R
08-24 17:10:50.655: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity org.adw.launcher/.Launcher
08-24 17:10:51.195: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40673a60 org.adw.launcher/.Launcher}
08-24 17:10:51.585: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-24 17:10:52.615: WARN/InputManagerService(61): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 589 uid 10039
08-24 17:10:53.015: INFO/Process(633): Sending signal. PID: 633 SIG: 9
08-24 17:10:53.035: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Process android.process.acore (pid 633) has died.
08-24 17:10:53.065: INFO/WindowManager(61): WIN DEATH: Window{406a12d0 org.adw.launcher/org.adw.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
08-24 17:10:57.465: DEBUG/dalvikvm(236): GC_EXPLICIT freed 13K, 51% free 2939K/5895K, external 716K/1038K, paused 80ms
08-24 17:11:02.158: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40673a60 org.adw.launcher/.Launcher}
```

Comment: Seeing the entire stacktrace makes things much easier

Comment: I was Edited My Question and add StackTrace in my Question.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya how u solve it tell me i got same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like some kind of infinite loop error, possibly in one or more of your drawables. Do you have one drawable which references a second, and the second has a circular reference back to the first? That might explain the kind of exception that you're seeing. It's difficult to be any more precise without seeing the drawables that you're trying to load.

Comment: Thanks Mark Allison, My Error is Solve Completely.